# reading text file java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to read a text file(.txt) in java. I need to eventually put the text I  extract word by word in a binary tree's nodes . If for example, I have the text: "Hi, I'm doing a test!", I would like to split it into "Hi" "I" "m" "doing" "a" "test", basically skipping all punctuation and empty spaces and considering a word to be a sequence of contiguous alphabet letters. I am so far able to extract the words and put them in an array for testing. However, if I have a completely empty line in my .txt file, the code will consider it as a word and return an empty space. Also, punctuation at the end of a line works but if there's a comma for example and then text, I will get an empty space as well ! Here is what I tried so far:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

 FileReader file = new FileReader("File.txt");  
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);


String text = "";
String line = reader.readLine();

    while (line != null)
{
    text += line;
    line = reader.readLine();
}
System.out.println(text);

String textnospaces=text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");

System.out.println(textnospaces);

String [] tokens = textnospaces.split("[\\W+]");

for(int i=0;i<=tokens.length-1;i++)
{
    tokens[i]=tokens[i].toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(tokens[i]);
}

}
```

Using the following text:

I can't, come see you. Today my friend is hard

s

I get the following output:

i

can

t
(extra space between "t" and "come")

come

see

you
(extra space again)

today

my

friend

is

hards

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: "Today my friend is hard" too much info

Answer (score 0):

use the `trim()` method of String. From documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29:

"Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

If this String object represents an empty character sequence, or the first and last characters of character sequence represented by this String object both have codes greater than '\u0020' (the space character), then a reference to this String object is returned.

Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020' in the string, then a new String object representing an empty string is created and returned.

Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'. A new String object is created, representing the substring of this string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m+1).

This method may be used to trim whitespace (as defined above) from the beginning and end of a string.

Returns:
    A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space."

Comment: I'm able to remove the space in between the characters, but I think it's my split function that's faulty !

Answer (score 0):

If you really are just looking for each contiguous sequence of characters, you can accomplish this with regex matching quite simply.

```
    String patternString1 = "([a-zA-Z]+)";
    String text = "I can't, come see you. Today my friend is hard";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
```